# Is it possible to install a port/package as static library on FreeBSD?

Tags: freebsd

I want to get a static library of graphics/devil, because I want to link it to my project statically. When I do pkg install devil or cd /usr/ports/graphics/devil && make install clean it makes the libIL.so but not libIL.a what I need.

What is the easiest way of getting a static library?

Comment: https://docs.freebsd.org/en/books/porters-handbook/new-port/ ? https://www.amoradi.org/20210912134132.html ?

Comment: Thank you, now I understand how ports works in FreeBSD :) I modified the existing port's cmake files to make the static libs instead of the shared objects.

Comment: Please consider posting an answer to your question stating more precisely what you did, so that your answer can be upvoted and (after a day or so) accepted.